# How to join every second line in Vim?

Tags: vim, normal-mode

I'd like to join a lot (~1000) of lines, but only every odd with the next one. By hand I could do

```
Jj
```

500 times and have it done. However, how can I execute these two statements 500 times in one single command? Typing

```
500Jj
```

will join the next 500 lines and *then* moving down one line.

Example:

I have:

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
```

I want:

```
a b
c d
e f
g h
```

*Edit:* I tried mapping:

```
:map X Jj
500X
```

but apparently I should read the mapping docs again. Doesn't work.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

i would do this:

1. start recording a macro 'q': `qqJjq`
2. replay the macro 'q' 500 times: `500@q`

(actually it is not a macro called 'q', it is a named register called 'q'. instead of interactively fill that register as in 1., you could also do `:let @q = "Jj"` and then do 2.)

Comment: :%normal J was very quick and easy (see 2nd top solution below)... compared to this macro solution running it on over 50,000 lines

Comment: @ihightower that's why i upvoted that answer as well. 6 years ago :)

Comment: @akira your macro just saved my day as i needed just this macro solution today for a different purpose.

Comment: Ideally a macro wouldn't be needed for something this simple, but the other answers (at least the ones that looked nice to me) didn't work for me unfortunately. This one didn't work for me either, due to there being a blank line between each set of lines that had text, but at least this solution allowed me to make the necessary modifications to get the job done for me. Inelegant but got the job done.

Answer (score 38):

To do this on every line of the file:

```
:%normal J
```

or, shorter:

```
:%norm J
```

To do this on just a portion of the file, select the lines with <kbd>V</kbd> or get a range some other way:

```
:'<,'>global/^/normal J
```

or, shorter:

```
:'<,'>g/^/norm J
```

Comment: Kevin he is looking to run two commands on every file, not just one.

Comment: the use of `:g` answers OP need.

Comment: This will indeed join every second line.  Try it!

Comment: Thanks for the `global` trick. In my case however, recording the macro was easier and faster.

Comment: Could anyone elaborate a bit on why this works, please? `:%normal J` executes J on all lines of the program, but why does it visually affect only half of them?

Comment: Just a guess -- it executes the command on each line in order, and after doing the first line, the second line is now gone (having been joined with the first line), so it is forced to move on to the third line.

Comment: For joining 3 rows, delighted to see that `:%norm JJJ` will work just as well

Comment: This doesn't seem to work properly

Answer (score 26):

What about this:

```
:g/$/j
```

or

```
:g/$/j!
```

and group every three lines

```
:g/$/j3
```

Comment: This is a VERY nice solution Miro.

It's even better in that you can use this in standard vi as well, although strangely, when you use the trailing number in SVR4.0 vi (as on Solaris) instead of j3 making 3 columns it makes 4. (so you need to use j2 there for grouping every 3 lines)

Comment: this is great! way quicker and cleaner than the actual accepted answer that record and redo the command n times!

Comment: I accidentally upvoted this, but it doesn't work for me, and there's no explanation of the difference between `j` and `j!` here.

Answer (score -1):

We can also play with:

```
'<,'>g//s/.*\zs\n\ze.*/ /
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm not a user of Vim, but checking the online docs it looks like

```
500(Jj)
```

might work since it parses things insides parentheses as a unit.

Comment: Hm, thanks for the try, but in my version Vim just ignores the parentheses. Could you tell me the link where you found this syntax?

Comment: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html - Sorry it didn't help!

Comment: Actually check this link:http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2136  see if that does what you are after.